# Grails - SQL NULL not allowed for column Error during a find

Tags: sql, grails

I'm working on GGTS 3.4 - Whilst creating an new instance of the domain model VideoDisplayMgmtShr I have introduced query check on the content of a domain model of an h2 dB prior to creating a new instance of that domain.  Here is the query:

```
def vidDispMgmLst = VideoDisplayMgmtShr.findAll{ displayMode == videoDisplayMgmtShrInstance.displayMode}
```

The error is:

```
 Class: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException
 Message: NULL not allowed for column "EXPIRY_DATE";
 SQL statement: insert into video_display_mgmt_shr ...
```

If I remove this check query the save of the new instance works fine - as the expiryDate is not null. I am doubly confused as the query is not creating a new instance so I don't see why it should throw this error? Also the expiryDate is set of null allowable in the model definition.

One last thing this domain model has a belongsTo constraint with another domain model - but that is all being taken care of in the create.

The domain class is:

```
class VideoDisplayMgmtShr {

// Defines the management of all videos that are published

static constraints = {
    description(blank:true, nullable:true)
    startDate(blank:true, nullable:true)
    expiryDate(blank:true, nullable:true)
    pubRights(inList:["Full", "Rest"]) // Full - full publish rights
                                    //Rest- Restricted rights - with a watermark for some concessionary publishing
    displayMode(inList:["Vanilla", "Vimeo", "YouTube"])

   }

static mapping = {
    datasource 'publish'
 }

String description
Date startDate = new Date()
Date expiryDate = new Date() + 100
String pubRights = "Rest"   // display type
String displayMode = "Vanilla" // type/ destination of publication
static belongsTo = [ publishedBT: PublishedShr]
```

}

With this domain class belongTo' another domain class:

```
static hasMany = [vidDMHM: VideoDisplayMgmtShr] // links to a display management entry
```

Not Sure is this is relevant but this has another mapping condiution:L

```
        static mapping = {

            datasource 'publish'

            vidDMHM cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
     }
```

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

-mike

Comment: Can you post some more details about the domain class that you're trying to save?

Comment: The class is:  `class VideoDisplayMgmtShr {
static constraints = {
 description(blank:true, nullable:true)
 startDate(blank:true, nullable:true)
 expiryDate(blank:true, nullable:true)
 pubRights(inList:["Full", "Rest"])
            displayMode(inList:["Vanilla", "Vimeo", "YouTube"])}
 
static mapping = {datasource 'publish'}
 String description
 Date startDate = new Date()
 Date expiryDate = new Date() + 100
 String pubRights = "Rest" 
 String displayMode = "Vanilla" 
 static belongsTo = [ publishedBT: PublishedShr]
}
`  With `static hasMany = [vidDMHM: VideoDisplayMgmtShr]` in another class.

Comment: @mikek you can edit your question and add the details there for readability.